# Meta-tagging question

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/) has retagged a couple of "bad" questions with tags that are, IMO, just as bad:

- <kbd>bad-question</kbd>: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475180/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657670/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324544/)
- <kbd>writing-before-thinking</kbd>: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475180/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474925/)

I'm not trying to single out a specific user, especially one who contributes so effectively (though admittedly, I spend next to zero time on <kbd>XSLT</kbd> questions, so this really doesn't have much to do with me). I also don't want to start an edit/rollback/re-edit/rollback/`GOTO 10` war.

What's the right course of action here? The retags seem [angry?|bitter?] but really just not helpful.

Comment: The guy has enough rep to comment and vote to close as well as down-voting. That's what he should do. I'm going to rollback the edits to remove the tags, though a couple are closed so I can't change those.

Comment: I've just noticed that he has voted to close at least one of the questions (at least there's a comment from him that says he has) so he does know the procedure. I guess he's just bitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right course of action is to rollback the bad tag edits (which I have done).

If the editor then reverts this the next step is to flag for moderator attention. In these cases this will probably result in the question post being locked.

The user has been a member for long enough to know how the site works and should know that meta tags aren't welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely flag this kind of stuff for moderator attention, because we want to know about it -- and we need your help to do so.

Hopefully flagging is a very low-friction way to point these things out.